# sql query working in phpmyadmin but not via mysql_query in php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Well first of all I am French so I hope my question will be understandable ;-)

I know some people have already experienced problems with queries in php that worked in phpmyadmin. The thing is that each time (or so) these people had "echo" their queries and copy/paste in phpmyadmin, but as php does not always display spaces it was always the problem.

Actually my problem is different :
if I use the query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jos_dtregister_invoice_sent"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

it returns all the rows in both phpmyadmin and my php code, but if I want to look in a different table (with same structure), it just works in phpmyadmin and not via my php code (only one row instead of all of them)

Here is the query not working:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jos_dtregister_receipt_sent";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Perhaps the answer is very simple but I admit this is kind of tricky for me...
Many thanks in advance!

Here is my complete code :

```
function sendReceipt($row) {

    $to = getUserInformation($row,10);
    $from = getEventAdminEmailFromEmail($row); 
    $subject = getEventTitle($row)." - Invoice #".$row["confirmNum"]; 

    $message = $row["userFirstName"]." ".$row["userLastName"]." \n\n".getMessageToSendUser($row); 
    $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `jos_dtregister_invoice_sent`";
    $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
    echo 'Fetched rows number: '.mysql_num_rows($query1)."<br />";
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            echo "Invoice Sent: ".$row1["sent"]."<br />";
    }
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `jos_dtregister_receipt_sent`";
    $query2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    echo 'Fetched rows number: '.mysql_num_rows($query2)."<br />";
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
            echo "Receipt Sent: ".$row2["sent"]."<br />";
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that `mysql_fetch_array()` only returns one row. So from the code you provided, this is the correct behavior.

Comment: What is the error message? `http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php`

Comment: I agree with wiseguy, check your connection and make sure it is a resource when using a var_dump()

Comment: Wow, 4 identical answers within 30 seconds.

Comment: Ok, first of all thank you for all your answers.
Actually I use a while loop to get all the rows of mysql_fetch_array(), the thing is that it returns only one row (it should returns 4). But it returns something... so there is no error message to help me!
And when I do this query on another similar table it works, so that is very weird...

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array() fetches only a row.The name suggests that it fetches a result row as an array

Comment: Actually I use a loop for mysql_fetch_array, as Shef and Michael advised me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jos_dtregister_receipt_sent";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Try to execute this. The mysql_error() line will spit out what exactly went wrong when trying to execute the SQL. Post it back here and we can help you a little more.

Comment: When I execute this it does nothing special, the thing is that the SQL query returns something but not all what it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jos_dtregister_receipt_sent";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // $row will have your data
}
```

Comment: I should have post my real code^^, I already use a loop. Actually when I mean there is only one row as a result it is only one row: mysql_num_rows($query) returns 1 with the second query, instead of 4 (this is for the moment a little table)

Comment: @François How many rows does the table `jos_dtregister_receipt_sent` have?

Comment: There are 4 rows in the table jos_dtregister_receipt_sent.

Comment: @François: OK. Add this `echo 'Fetched rows number: '.mysql_num_rows($result);`, before `while`, and tell us what it outputs.

Comment: @Shef It outputs an empty string (or nothing if you prefer)

Comment: Does it output exactly this `Fetched rows number: `?

Comment: @Shef yes it output exactly Fetched rows number:

Comment: Try changing the query to this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM \`jos_dtregister_receipt_sent\`";` and run the script again to tell us what it outputs.

Comment: I also tried this on the query that works and it also returns  Fetched rows number: ,are you sure about mysql_num_rows($result) and not mysql_num_rows($query)?

Comment: @François: Hmm... I gave you that, based on the code I have suggested above. If you have not changed your code to match the one I am suggesting above, then it should be `mysql_num_rows($query)`.

Comment: @Shef I tried $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jos_dtregister_receipt_sent`"; but it does the same.

Comment: Ok, what does it output for the second query?

Comment: For the one that works it outputs Fetched rows number: 4 (this table has also 4 rows at the moment)

Comment: and for the other it is just Fetched rows number: 1 (not "", as I use the good word^^)

Comment: @François: Hmm... Please post all your code, the way you have it now. I mean all of it, from the first query to the last query. You might be missing something trivial.

Comment: @François: Do not post it here on the comments!!! At the end of your question, there is an [`Edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6470573/edit) link, click that one and place the code at the end of your question.

Comment: The param of the function is used later in the function, but there is no new query anymore.

Comment: Hmm... there seems nothing wrong with the code. The only question that remains is, do you have another database with the same table? Where do you do the database connection, maybe you are connecting to two different databases?

Comment: I use this table in only one database, but actually I also think this problem is linked with the database...because for me too it seems the code is good! 
What I really want to do is more complicated but when I wanted to debug I saw that everything I do about the 'receipt' table is not working, and everything else I do with others tables is working!
I only connect one database...

Comment: @François: Can you try inserting a row, to see if the the record will go to this table?

Comment: I inserted a row within the function and it worked.
And now the query detects 2 rows... (instead of 5)

Comment: @François: Are you by any fraction of a chance looking at the wrong table?

Comment: @Shef I wish it was something like that but no, I inserted in the same table I would like to look in. And the only row I get from the query (and the second now) shows me it is on this table...

Comment: Ok I think I will try to do something else in order to not make this sql query, like to parse this variable in my other files, because I do not see what can be the answer to this... Thank you a lot for the time you spent with me, I really appreciate this!

Comment: Try adding this before your second query: `$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) \`rows_count\` FROM \`jos_dtregister_receipt_sent\`"; $query2 = mysql_query($sql2); $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2); echo 'Results count: '.$row2['rows_count'];`

Comment: @Shef It outputs Results count: 1Fetched rows number: 1 (Results count: 2Fetched rows number: 2 if I let the Insert statement before)

Comment: @François: Hmm... try to run the above query somewhere else, on some clean file, which includes only the database connection and nothing else.

Comment: @Shef this time it outputs Results count: 1Fetched rows number: 4

Comment: But when I copy/paste the function directly in the file I use it, it still bugs. I guess I have to not use an auxiliary function... Thank you Shef!

Comment: @François: You are definitely fetching from two different tables or databases. Run this query on phpMyAdmin `SELECT COUNT(*) \`rows_count\` FROM \`jos_dtregister_receipt_sent\``, and tell me what is the number of the `rows_count`?

Comment: I mean my code is more condensed now, but at least it works! :-)

Comment: @François: If you found a way to bypass this problem, use that. However, I still think the problem lies on your database connection handler.

Comment: Actually this is possible, I use a lot of different files where I need to connect to the same database, perhaps that when I different functions are called from different files there is connection problem (even if it is just on one table and not others...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the results with `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  print_r($result);
}
```

Or if you want all your results in one big array ($results):

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $results[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I should have post my real code^^, I already use a loop.
Actually when I mean there is only one row as a result it is only one row: mysql_num_rows($query) returns 1 with the second query, instead of 4 (this is for the moment a little table)